# How to refer to variables in induction

Tags: isabelle

I have a function which is matching on lists:

```
fun merge where
  ‹merge [] [] = []› |
  ‹merge (v#vs) [] = (v#vs)› |
  ‹merge [] (v#vs) = (v#vs)› |
  ‹merge (x#xs) (y#ys) =
    (if x < y then x # merge xs (y#ys) else y # merge (x#xs) ys)›
```

When I'm trying to prove the correctness of this I'm having difficulties with induction based on this:

```
...
lemma sorted_merge: 
  assumes s_xs: "sorted(xs)"
    and   s_ys: "sorted(ys)"
  shows ‹sorted(merge xs ys)›  
proof (induction xs ys rule: merge.induct [case_names base xs ys both])
  case base then show "?case" by auto
next
  case xs
  show "?case" 
  proof -
```

The issue is that I can prove that this case for `sorted(merge xs [])` but this doesn't satisify `sorted(merge (v#vs) [])` which is the proof goal.

Hence how do I fix `xs` to be `v#vs`, or to otherwise refer to the case analysed `xs` for this specific case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hence how do I fix xs to be `v#vs`, or to otherwise refer to the case
> analysed `xs` for this specific case?

This is explained in section 6.5 of the reference manual of Isabelle2020 (Isar-ref):

> ... By using the explicit form `case (c y1 ... ym)` ... the proof
> author is able to chose local names that fit nicely into the current
> context ...

Thus, in your case, you can use something similar to

```
fun merge where
  ‹merge [] [] = []› 
| ‹merge (v#vs) [] = (v#vs)› 
| ‹merge [] (v#vs) = (v#vs)› 
| ‹merge (x#xs) (y#ys) = 
    (if x < y then x # merge xs (y#ys) else y # merge (x#xs) ys)›

lemma sorted_merge:
  assumes s_xs: "sorted(xs)" and s_ys: "sorted(ys)"
  shows ‹sorted(merge xs ys)›  
  using assms
proof(induction xs ys rule: merge.induct[case_names base xs ys both])
  case base then show ?case by auto
next
  case (xs v vs) then show ?case by auto
next
  case (ys v vs) then show ?case by auto
next
  case (both x xs y ys)
  show ?case 
  proof(cases ‹x < y›)
    case True with both(1,3,4) show ?thesis by (induction xs) force+
  next
    case False with both(2,3,4) show ?thesis by (induction ys) force+
  qed      
qed
```

---

Isabelle version: Isabelle2020